# Android Wear Message Api Not Working

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Android Wear Java I'm having some trouble finding out how to implement the Wear to Phone call using the Message Api. Can someone give me a simple working example or help me out here?
This is my code for testing...

> **Wear MainJava**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MessageActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });

        // Register the local broadcast receiver
        IntentFilter messageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(messageReceiver, messageFilter);
    }

    public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.v("myTag", "Main activity received message: " + message);
            // Display message in UI
            mTextView.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

> **Wear Listener Service**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService;

public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals("/message_path")) {
            final String message = new String(messageEvent.getData());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message path received on watch is: " + messageEvent.getPath());
            Log.v("myTag", "Message received on watch is: " + message);

            // Broadcast message to wearable activity for display
            Intent messageIntent = new Intent();
            messageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            messageIntent.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
        }
        else {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        }
    }

}
```

> **and  the mobile(phone)**

```
package com.spokengiovannie.messageactivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;


public class MessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleApiClient googleClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        // Build a new GoogleApiClient that includes the Wearable API
        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    // Connect to the data layer when the Activity starts
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleClient.connect();
    }

    // Send a message when the data layer connection is successful.
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String message = "Hello wearable\n Via the data layer";
        //Requires a new thread to avoid blocking the UI
        new SendToDataLayerThread("/message_path", message).start();
    }

    // Disconnect from the data layer when the Activity stops
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (null != googleClient && googleClient.isConnected()) {
            googleClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    // Placeholders for required connection callbacks
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) { }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

    // Unused project wizard code
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_message, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread {
        String path;
        String message;

        // Constructor to send a message to the data layer
        SendToDataLayerThread(String p, String msg) {
            path = p;
            message = msg;
        }

        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleClient).await();
            for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleClient, node.getId(), path, message.getBytes()).await();
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.v("myTag", "Message: {" + message + "} sent to: " + node.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    // Log an error
                    Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send Message");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All this code is from a tutorial. When I launch de app on the phone it suppose to change the textView wear text. Someone have a sample or app already made for contact the phone I'm stuck :(.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageIntent) in your WearableListenerService. This is a local broadcast which will not be delivered to the phone.

[see API doc LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you figured it by now but for the fresh lads like me this might help.

Add listener service to the respective class, in this example this is the code.
Add this in your Wear's `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<service android:name=".ListenerService">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```